# What do vector field singularities represent?

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

I've been learning about line integrals in vector fields and am a little confused about singularities.

From my understanding, a closed line integral in a conservative field is always $0$ unless it goes around a singularity.  In addition, going around a singularity accounts for a certain change in the value of the line integral.

My question is: What does the value added by integrating around a singularity represent?  I am assuming it represents something because going around the singularity with any path results in the same value.  Is there a physical meaning for what the value represents?

Comment: There are a couple of misconceptions here: (1) Given a conservative vector field ${\bf F}$ and a nice, closed path $\gamma$, it's *always* true that
$$\int_\gamma {\bf F} \cdot d{\bf s} = 0 .$$ In fact, we can even take this to be the definition of conservative. (In the $2$-dimensional case, the condition you have in mind is not conservativeness but rather the vanishing of the quantity $Q_x - P_y$.)

Comment: (2) There are vector fields like $${\bf V} := \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} (-y {\bf i} + x {\bf j})$$ (defined on $\Bbb R^2 - \{(0, 0)\}$) that satisfy $Q_x - P_y = 0$ but for which there are paths $\gamma$ (e.g., any nice loop that encloses the origin once) such that $\int_\gamma {\bf V} \cdot d{\bf s} \neq 0$. But the vector field ${\bf V}\vert_U$, where $U := \{(x, y) : x^2 + y^2 > 1\}$ has no "singularity", as $||{\bf V}\vert_U(x, y)|| < 1$ for all $(x, y) \in U$.

Comment: All that said, one can still ask for the meaning of the path integral around a hole in the domain of a vector field satisfying $Q_x - P_y = 0$, but the physical interpretation depends on physical context, just the meaning of a regular integral $\int_a^b f(x) \,dx$ of a function $f$ of one variable does.

Comment: Conservativity is locally equivalent to irrotation, i.e. the field does not have distributed whirling that induces going in circles. A singularity can represent a vortex concentrated at a point, rather than distributed, see [Wikipedia's image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields).